SERVER TIMESTAMP for Realtime Database in Cloud Functions (Python)
To get the SERVER TIMESTAMP for firestore, it is
from firebase_admin import firestore
...
{"createdAt": firestore.firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP}

but how to get the SERVER TIMESTAMP for Realtime Database?
from firebase_admin import db

@https_fn.on_call()
def f1(req: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    ...
    db.reference(f"users/{userId}").set({"createdAt": # SERVER TIMESTAMP refrence ?? })


https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/284#issuecomment-488503908

As Doug and I linked, you can tell Firebase to write a server-side timestamp by sending {".sv": "timestamp"} as the value.
